# How to draw an specific bar chart mixed with Gantt chart

Tags: charts

I'm trying to draw this chart. I found some tutorials explaining some generic examples. I tried by myself, but couldn't figure it out how to do exactly how I really need.

The "x" axis is the time, and "y" is the resource amount. The line that started in "4" is my resource limit to be used. And each box is a task. The first box, "2", means that the task "2" use 3 of resource between the interval "0" and "4"

I really appreciate some "north" here in how to handle with this.

Cheers

[image: Chart that I want!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,10)

\psaxes{->}(0,0)(14,5)

\psline[linestyle=dashed](0,4)(13.5,4)

\psline(0,3)(4,3)(4,4)(9,4)(9,2)(10,2)(10,4)(12,4)(12,3)(13,3)(13,0)
\psline(4,0)(4,3)
\psline(6,0)(6,4)
\psline(6,2)(10,2)
\psline(10,0)(10,4)
\psline(12,0)(12,3)

\rput[c](2,1.5){$2$}
\rput[c](5,2){$4$}
\rput[c](8,1){$6$}
\rput[c](7.5,3){$1$}
\rput[c](11,2){$3$}
\rput[c](12.5,1.5){$5$}
\rput[b](14,-0.5){$t$}
\rput[r](-0.2,5){$R_1$}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]